# How to directly query a relational/SQL database from a ZOPE product?

Tags: python, sql, zope

How do I connect to and query a relational database that was configured with a DA e.g. ZPsycopgDA in a Zope product?

I want to send my own SQL queries using bound parameters and receive the results preferrable as a set of Result objects.

I don't want to use ZSQLMethods as I can't create one for every query beforehand, and ZSQLMethods don't support bound parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zope Database Adapters (DA) code base is some of the oldest code still in use in Zope, and is thus somewhat archaic. When you call a Zope DA, you get a database connection object (a DB instance) that in turn has a query method:

```
connection = context.idOfZPsycoPGDA()
connection.query('SELECT * FROM your_table')
```

The query method is not exactly a Python database API standard method. It accepts multiple SQL statements separated by `\0` null characters, but won't support SELECTs if there is more than one statement.

The ZPsychoDA query method also accepts query parameters:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id=?', ('yourid',))
```

but more importantly, the ZPsychoDA adapter also gives you access to a regular database cursor:

```
c = connection.cursor()
c.query('SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id=?', ('yourid',))
```

My advise is to just use that and do regular Python DB API calls via the database cursor you get there.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I found the result format from connection.query() a bit strange but you get a nice resultset with Shared.DC.ZRDB.Results.Results(result).

Answer (score 1):

The database connector instances should provide a query() method accepting a SQL command. And you get hold of the database adapter instance through acquisition (or traversal via restrictedTraverse('/path/to/da'):

```
result = context.my_zpyscopgda.query("select * from foo")

result = context.restrictedTraverse('/path/to/my_zpyscopgda').query("select * from foo")
```